# RequireJS Load timeout for modules: error detail

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, js-amd

I need to expose better error detail from requireJS "load timeout for modules" errors so I can actually debug to find out what is causing the load timeout.

I'm unable to get the error to appear on my development machine, but roughly 10% of our daily visitors are experiencing this error in the production environment (track.js is being used to gather these errors for visibility).

- The error is being thrown for my main.js file ("load timeout for modules: main") - the application entry point.  I've added the errback callback to try to log the error detail here but this error doesn't seem to hit this callback so it seems as though everything main.js is requiring is fine.
- I've added a global override for requirejs.onError and all I get here is the module name (main.js) and an error code of timeout.
- I've used madge and have verified that there are no circular dependencies.
- I have optimized the build using r.js optimizer.
- I have set waitSeconds: 0 in require config (by my understanding should disable the timeout completely)

How can I find out what module that is being required somewhere down the line is actually causing the timeout? Anything further to go on would be very helpful - I'm finding this incredibly hard to track down.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from James Burke himself. .....However if the difficulty is that your "main" is taking a long time to load, that script holds the requirejs.config() call with waitSeconds, and it was loaded via data-main, then the requirejs.config() call may not be called in time for it to be useful. For that issue, you can pass waitSeconds using "requirejs as initial config".

   `<script>var requirejs = { waitSeconds: 0 };</script>`

    `<script src="require.js" data-main="main"></script>`

This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can set [waitSeconds](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds) in config of requireJS. By default it's 7 seconds. I do not know the exact answer to your question but this can be a temporary solution. Probably someone from users has a very slow internet. and it is not enough 7 seconds.

You can test in in `Chrome devTools` -> `Network tab` -> `Throtling selector`. And select for example "2G regular 450 kb/c". I assume that you will see this error. Also, this error sometimes occurred when I used CDN.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I have set waitSeconds to 0 already too.  Network throttling is a good idea.  I set it to 2G regular - interestingly I could see in the network panel the main.js script loaded without error, but I still received the load timeout for modules: main error.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @cre8ive

Comment: Yes, from James Burke himself.

.....However if the difficulty is that your "main" is taking a long time to 
load, that script holds the requirejs.config() call with waitSeconds, 
and it was loaded via data-main, then the requirejs.config() call may 
not be called in time for it to be useful. For that issue, you can 
pass waitSeconds using "requirejs as initial config".

<script>var requirejs = { waitSeconds: 0 };</script> 
<script src="require.js" data-main="main"></script>